# how can I render datalist tag with slim-lang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

To render views in the Ruby on Rails application I am using slim-lang, in one of my views I would like to have the `<datalist>` tag, with pre-field options how this will be possible with slim-lang.

**UPDATE**

`= datalist :languages, options_for_select(@languages)`

Comment: I recommend familiarizing yourself with the [Slim documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames). It's a very lightweight templating engine, so it's a pretty quick read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slim will simply convert whatever you pass to HTML, have you tried:

```
datalist#browsers
  - ["Internet Explorer", "Firefox"].each do |browser|
    option value=browser
```

Comment: This looks swell, my additional question will be is there a chance to generate the options from the array?

Comment: See updated answer. Short answer YES, but that's outside of Slim, you simply do a loop, remember it's still Ruby.